# Python print indentations

Tags: python, string, printing

In Python 3.x how do you print an indent of white space, the method I am looking for looked something like this

```
level = 3
print ('% indent symbol' % * level, 'indented text')
```

should print:

```
            indented text
```

repeating answer from below: thanks to @sudo_coffee for \t

```
print ('\t' * level, 'indented text')
```

or maybe:

```
print ((' ' * 4) * level, 'indented text')
```

Comment: Apart from the syntax error, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

sorry guys, think I found the answer, thanks to @sudo_coffee for \t

```
print ('\t' * level + 'indented text')
```

or maybe:

```
print ((' ' * 4) * level + 'indented text')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
level = 3
print (" "*level, 'indented text')
```

Answer (score 1):

To indent, or enter a "tab" amount of space, use the escape sequence `\t`.

```
level = 3
print ('\t indented text')
```

Comment: I have found the answer: print ('\t' * level, 'indented text')

Answer (score 0):

```
level = 3
indented_symbol = "    "

print '{} Indented text'.format(indented_symbol*level)
```